# Как получить аргументы функции?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Есть исходник

```
void some_func()
{
    SOME_CODE_HERE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    some_func(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Как из функции `some_func` получить аргументы без ассемблерных вставок?
2. Зачем вообще в Си было ввведено различие между объявлением

-

```
void some_func() {}
```

и

```
void some_func(void) {}
```

P.S.:

На всякий пожарный: крики "твоё творение не компилится" не принимаются, потому что это враки и gcc всё компилит даже без варнингов.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL20-C.+Always+specify+void+even+if+a+function+accepts+no+arguments

Comment: Спасибо, именно то что нужно:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Для 32-bit такой фокус возможен, т.к. компилятор передает параметры через стек. В нем же запоминается base pointer (регистр от которого берутся смещения локальных переменных и параметров). Поэтому, если вспомогательная функция вернет значение bp интересующей нас функции, то мы имеем доступ к аргументам.

   Короче

   ```
   int **getbp (int arg)
   {
       /* caller bp (arg[-2] == bp; arg[-1] == return_addr; arg[0] == arg) */
       return (int **)(&arg-2); 
   }


   void some_func()
   {
       //SOME_CODE_HERE;
       write(1,"xaxa\n",5);
       int **bp = getbp(1);
       int *args = *bp + 2;

       printf ("%d %d %d\n",args[0],args[1],args[2]);
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       some_func(1, 2, 3);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Использование:

   ```
   c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc noargs.c 
   c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
   xaxa
   1 2 3
   c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
   ```

   В 64-bit х86 gcc такая штука не пройдет, так как несколько  параметров (в данном случае все) передаются через регистры.

   Вы можете посмотреть ассемблерный код (в файле noargs.s) командой:

   ```
   gcc -S noargs.c
   ```
2. @Котик_хочет_кушать видимо [ответил вам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/151667/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/151697#comment151678_151667) (я не вчитывался в аргументацию).

**Update**

По крайней мере в gcc 5.4.0 (проверял в Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) в x86_64 GNU/Linux параметры передаются в функцию в [регистрах](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#x86_registers).

Первые 6 целых (включая указатели) в регистрах **rdi**, **rsi**, **rdx**, **rcx**, **r8** и **r9**, а первые 8 действительныx (`float` и `double`) в регистрах с **xmm0** по **xmm7**. Остальные помещаются в стек в обратном порядке. Т.е. параметры, которые находились в списке вызова функции ближе к его началу, окажутся ближе к вершине стека (в памяти с меньшими адресами, поскольку стек растет от старших адресов к младшим).

Идея извлечения значений параметров без использования ассемблера состоит в том, что надо "обмануть" компилятор и вызвать без аргументов  функцию у которой определен подходящий список аргументов, которые она должна положить в память и вернуть эту память в `some_func()`. Проблема в том, что вызов (и возврат результата) надо проделать так, чтобы компилятор эти регистры (он же, компилируя `some_func()` считает, что у нее нет параметров) не попортил.

Что касается параметров, которые не поместились в регистры и записаны в стек, то мне удалось достать их только в том случае, когда все функции компилируются без оптимизации.

В таком случае gcc адресует каждый фрейм функции (ее локальные переменные) регистром **rbp** (при входе в функцию он запоминается в стеке и загружается новым значением указателя стека (**rsp**))  и связывает их в список.
(*самому жутко интересно, каким образом отладчик находит фреймы для программы с оптимизацией?

Кое-что можно прочесть [тут](http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/05/deep-wizardry-stack-unwinding.html), возможно основное там* --

> gdb has a whole bunch of unwinders, including one that scans the
>   machine code to figure out how the frame was setup.

*что явно выносит попытки написания корректного примера для оптимизированного кода за рамки этого вопроса*)

Итак, имеем такую программу (main и some_func)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "getargs64.h"


void some_func()
{
  GETARGS64(arg);

  puts("some_func integer:");
  for (int i = 0; i < N_IREGS || (puts(""), 0); i++)
    printf("%ld ", arg.ir[i]);

  puts("some_func float:");  
  for (int i = 0; i < N_FREGS || (puts(""), 0); i++)
    printf("%f ", arg.fr[i]);

  if (arg.sa.isa)
    printf("args in stack: [%ld %ld %ld %lf %lf %lf %ld %ld]\n",
       arg.sa.isa[0], arg.sa.isa[1], arg.sa.isa[2],
       arg.sa.fsa[3], arg.sa.fsa[4], arg.sa.fsa[5],
       arg.sa.isa[6], arg.sa.isa[7]);
  else
    puts("can't get args in stack");

  //SOME_CODE_HERE;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  some_func(1, 2, 3, 11.1, 12.1, 13.1, 4, 5, 6, 14.1, 15.1, 16.1, 17.1, 18.1,
        7, 8, 9, 17.2, 18.2, 19.2, 7001, 7002, 7001.7, 7002.8);

  puts("again X 10");
  some_func(110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60,
        140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 170.1, 180.1,
        70, 80, 90, 170.2, 180.2, 190.2);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Для реализации нашего плана пишем вот такой заголовочный файл (getargs.h)

```
#ifndef _GETARGS64_H
#define _GETARGS64_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_IREGS 6
#define N_FREGS 8

uint64_t *get_iregs();
double *get_fregs();
uint64_t *get_stackargs (uint64_t a, ...);

struct regargs {
  uint64_t ir[N_IREGS];
  double fr[N_FREGS];
  union {
    uint64_t *isa;
    double *fsa;
  } sa;
};

// макрос определен gcc, если он вызван с ключами оптимизации
#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__                                    
#define STACKARGS(name) name.sa.isa = get_stackargs(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,   \
                                                   get_stackargs)
#else
#define STACKARGS(name)      name.sa.isa = 0
#endif

#define GETARGS64(name) struct regargs name;            \
  {                                                     \
    uint64_t *iargs = get_iregs();                      \
    double *fargs = get_fregs();                        \
                                                        \
    for (int i = 0; i < N_IREGS; i++)                   \
      name.ir[i] = iargs[i];                            \
    for (int i = 0; i < N_FREGS; i++)                   \
      name.fr[i] = fargs[i];                            \
    free(iargs); free(fargs);                           \
    STACKARGS(name);                                    \
  }

#endif
```

с макросом `GETARGS64(name)`, который надо разместить в первой строке `some_func()`. Этот макрос создает структуру `struct regargs` с именем *name*, которая будет заполнена значениями регистров и (если возможно) указателем на оставшиеся параметры `some_func` в стеке.

И наконец, сами функции, извлекающие значения регистров и параметры вызова в стеке:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>


#define N_IREGS 6
#define N_FREGS 8

uint64_t *
get_iregs (uint64_t a0, uint64_t a1, uint64_t a2,
            uint64_t a3, uint64_t a4, uint64_t a5)
{
  uint64_t r[N_IREGS] = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};

  return memcpy(malloc(N_IREGS * sizeof(uint64_t)),
                r, N_IREGS * sizeof(uint64_t));
}

double *
get_fregs (double a0, double a1, double a2, double a3,
           double a4, double a5, double a6, double a7)
{
  double *fr = malloc(N_FREGS * sizeof(double));

  fr[0] = a0; fr[1] = a1; fr[2] = a2; fr[3] = a3;
  fr[4] = a4; fr[5] = a5; fr[6] = a6; fr[7] = a7;

  return fr;
}

#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__

#define ARGS_OFFSET 2

#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <errno.h>

// check memory access by addr, returns 1 if addr readable/writable, 0 otherwise
static int
is_mem_accessible (void *addr, int writable)
{
  if (addr == 0 || addr == (void *)-1LL)
    return 0;
  volatile int rc = 1;
  sigjmp_buf jmp;

  // signal handler nested function
  void sighdr (int sig) { siglongjmp(jmp, 0); }
  void 
    (* sigbus)(int) = signal(SIGBUS, sighdr), 
    (* sigsegv)(int) = signal(SIGSEGV, sighdr);

  if (sigsetjmp(jmp, 1)) { // MANDATORY save sigmask
    rc = 0;
    errno = EFAULT;
  } else {
    volatile char t = *((char *)addr);
    if (writable)
      *((char *)addr) = t;
  }

  signal(SIGBUS, sigbus);
  signal(SIGSEGV, sigsegv);

  return rc;
}

uint64_t *
get_stackargs (uint64_t a, ...)
{
  uint64_t *p;

  for (p = (uint64_t *)(&p + 1); *p != (uint64_t)get_stackargs; p++);
  p = (uint64_t *)p[-2];

  return is_mem_accessible (p + ARGS_OFFSET, 1) ?
    p + ARGS_OFFSET : 0;
}

#else

uint64_t *
get_stackargs (uint64_t a, ...)
{
  return 0;
}
#endif
```

Если есть какие-то вопросы, задавайте в комментариях (или чате C/C++), попробуем разобраться.