# Зачем нужен ebp, если можно без него

Tags: ассемблер

Зачем нужно использовать регистр ebp при организации стека программы, если можно обойтись и без него(если нет хитрых асм вставок)? Почему нельзя по умолчанию использовать такую оптимизацию? С чем это связанно?

Comment: Приведите примеры того, про какое использование ebp тут речь и про какую вы  оптимизацию говорите

Comment: @Mike: Ну, адресовать локальные переменные и параметры можно теоретически и через ESP, если внимательно следить за текущим количеством выделенной на стеке памяти. В вопросе, скорее всего, имеется в виду адресация локальных переменных и параметров подпрограммы через EBP.

Comment: x86_64 ABI в принципе об этом же и пишет: *The conventional use of %rbp as a frame pointer for the stack frame may be avoided by using %rsp (the stack pointer) to index into the stack frame. This technique saves two instructions in the prologue and epilogue and makes one additional general-purpose register (%rbp) available.*

Comment: Во всей этой дискуссии (вопрос, ответы, комментарии) меня удивляет одно, неужели никто никогда не слышал про магическое ABI?

Comment: @0andriy, а что это меняет? Компилятор сам разберётся как ему адресовать стек и нужны ли пролог/эпилог в каждом конкретном случае. Вручную же - личное дело программиста,  никто не мешает ему делать как угодно. ABI говорит лишь об организации стека, но не накладывает никаких ограничений на способы работы с ним.

Comment: @PinkTux, компилятор *следует* ABI.

Comment: @0andriy, а где в ABI сказано, что к стеку нужно обращаться только через определённый регистр?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Связано это в первую очередь с удобством. Никто не мешает вам адресоваться через регистр `esp`. Но при этом нужно постоянно держать в голове что сам стековый указатель в процессе выполнения кода может прыгать как угодно. И постоянно менять смещение для одних и тех же сущностей (а вам было бы удобно, если сейчас переменная называется `foo`, а через пару строк к ней нужно обращаться как к `bar`?). В совсем простеньких случаях это может иметь смысл, сам так делаю :) Например:

```
print_uint:
    pushad
    push dword [esp+36]
    push format_u ; "%u", 0
    call printf
    pop eax
    pop eax
    popad
    ret 4
```

Да и компиляторы могут генерировать код без `enter/leave` при оптимизации. Но в общем случае это "микрооптимизация" (и то под вопросом), и не стоит она того геморроя, который за собой тащит.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без него ([а очень жаль иногда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/151667/232)).

Например, gcc для тестовой программки

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {
  return puts("xaxa");
}

int main(void) 
{
  long a = 10;
  long long b = 11;
  int l = 100;
  float e = 8.8;

  f(a, b, l, e);

  return 0;
}
```

с флагами оптимизации

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc -O -S t.c
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc --vers
gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

делает код без использования **ebp**(**rbp**) для организации фреймов стека

```
        .file   "t.c"
        .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string "xaxa"
        .text
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE23:
        .size   f, .-f
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB24:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        movl    $100, %edx
        movl    $11, %esi
        movl    $10, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        call    f
        movl    $0, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE24:
        .size   main, .-main
        .section        .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
        .align 8
.LC1:
        .long   2684354560
        .long   1075943833
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Кстати, вот что интересно стало: а может ли оптимизатор не восстанавливать стек после каждого вызова `cdecl`-функции, если в этом нет явной необходимости? А сделать это, например, один раз перед `ret`. Проверить, конечно, можно, но сегодня уже лень :)

Comment: @PinkTux, мне вообще непонятно, зачем тут `subq    $8, %rsp`. Кстати, с -O3 тело `f()` сокращается до 2-х команд: `movl $.LC0, %edi` ;
 `jmp puts` (однако, `call f` остается)

Comment: Да, точно :) http://pastebin.com/ZcuVXUnt

Comment: @avp, секция 3.2.2 x86_64 ABI проясняет этот (%rsp) момент.

Comment: @0andriy, каким образом? Если вы о `In other words, the value
(
%rsp
+ 8)
is always
a multiple of
16
(
32
) when control is transferred to the function entry point.`, так это (если посмотреть на код)  еще больше все запутывает.

Comment: Извиняюсь, только что дошло. Именно требование выравнивания заставляет компилятор вычитать 8 из %rsp. Стек был выровнен на 16, после call он не выровнен (поместили адрес возврата), для выравнивания достаточно вычесть 8.