# C++ вызов функции от переменной

Tags: c++

Как вызвать ф-ию, с переменной в C++, вот пример

```
char* funcName = "somefunction";
char* params[] = {"param1", "param2", "param3"};
callFunction(funcName, params);
```

Так вот, как можно реализовать ф-ию "callFunction", чтоб она вызывало другие ф-ии, как нелепо бы это было сказано.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Ну так вы ее и вызвали :) Вопрос как-то понятнее сформулируйте?

Comment: Я привел пример, ф-ия "callFunction", должна как-то вызвать ту ф-ию, которая в переменной "funcName".
Я это имел ввиду, но не знаю как это сделать

Comment: @HackMemory, функции с одинаковыми сигнатурами?

Comment: @Harry, автор хочет вызвать функцию `someFunction` с параметрами `params`. То есть `someFunction(params)`, но само имя функции у него лежит в строковой переменной. [Аналогичный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442101/calling-a-function-using-a-string-containing-the-functions-name) на англоязычном ресурсе.

Comment: В `funcName` у вас строка, а не функция. Рефлексии в C++ нет, непосредственно - никак, опосредованно - создавайте, например, массив структур с именем и адресом, ищите адрес по имени и вызывайте...

Comment: Стандартными средствами  это невозможно. Есть обходные возможности, зависящее от платформы и/или используемого фреймворка. Уточните, хотя бы платформу, а желательно сформулируйте задачу более высокого уровня (зачем этот вызов понадобился).

Comment: если сделать так, что бы функции были функциями, экспортируемыми (с дополнительной dll, хотя вроде можно экспортировать и с самого бинаря), тогда все стает сильно проще:)

Comment: Вызывать нужно ф-ии из dll, точнее gtk+
Пример, нужно вызвать ф-ию "gtk_window_set_title". Добавив параметр GtkWidget и gchar. Но как это сделать, я не знаю.
ОС, желательно под linux и windows. А какая разница имеет ОС?

Comment: В данном случае уже имеет - Вам по разному нужно функцию получать. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538103/how-to-call-a-function-from-a-shared-library

Comment: Если из DLL - то это можно через [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), но это - применение API, а не сам язык :) Вопрос следовало задать точнее... В Linux другие способы, но это не ко мне, там я не в курсе. И еще раз, чтобы вы отдавали себе отчет - это вопрос не по **языку**, а по **API** соответствующей ОС.

Comment: А как тогда это работает в Java, Python или PHP. 
Это из за того, что они интерпретируемые языки?

Comment: Все это вполне программируемо на Си (и С++). Читайте [man dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), а также  `SEE ALSO` там

Comment: @HackMemory это Java-то интерпретируемый?..

Comment: Ошибся, там виртуальная машина

Comment: @avp для dlopen (в частности dlsym) необходимо заранее знать прототип функции. Если он у них одинаковый, то да, этот вариант подходит.

Comment: @AccumPlus, если по всем правилам, то да, надо знать. Конечно, знать какие аргументы передавать, надо в любом случае. Иногда, обладая таким знанием только динамически (не во время компиляции) все же можно это хакнуть и вызвать функцию. В доказательство своих слов предлагаю посмотреть на gdb

Answer (score 1):

Получилось довольно коряво, но работает.

В предлагаемом методе должны выполняться следующие условия:

- Функции должны "лежать" в динамических библиотеках;
- Функции должны иметь тип void* (void*).

Пример файла исходных кодов с функциями:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void* func0(void *args)
{
    std::tuple<int, int> *t = (std::tuple<int, int> *)args;

    int result = std::get<0>(*t) + std::get<1>(*t);
    return std::move((void *)&(result));
}

extern "C" void* func1(void *args)
{
    std::tuple<std::string, std::string> *t = (std::tuple<std::string, std::string> *)args;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(*t) << ' ' << std::get<1>(*t) << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Компилируем:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared functions.cpp -o libfunctions.so
```

Чтобы получить список имён функций (символов) и сохранить их указатель, воспользуемся возможностями библиотек **libdlfcn** и **libbfd**.

Хранить соответствия "Имя функции -> Указатель" будем в следующем **std::map**:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void*(void*)> > functions;
```

Вызов функций выполняет следующая функция. Входные параметры: Имя функции, набор параметров через запятую. Возвращаемое значение - указатель типа void на то, что должна вернуть функция.

```
template<typename ... Args>
void* callFunction(const std::string &funcName, Args... args)
{
    std::tuple<Args...> t = {args...};
    return functions[funcName](&t);
}
```

Для возможности вызова функций из внешней библиотеки необходимо держать "хэндлер" на эту библиотеку.

```
void * handle;
```

Функция заполнения мэпа. Входные параметры: путь до библиотеки. Возвращаемое значение - EXIT_FAILURE или EXIT_SUCCESS.

```
int start(const std::string& libName)
{
    bfd * abfd = bfd_openr(libName.c_str(), 0);
    if (abfd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at openning: " << libName << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    (void) bfd_check_format(abfd, bfd_object);

    handle = dlopen(libName.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at dlopen: " << libName << std::endl;
        bfd_close(abfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    long storage_needed = bfd_get_symtab_upper_bound(abfd);
    if (storage_needed <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at get storage: " << libName << std::endl;
        bfd_close(abfd);
        dlclose(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    asymbol **symbol_table = (asymbol**) calloc (storage_needed, sizeof(char));
    if (symbol_table == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at calloc: " << libName << std::endl;
        bfd_close(abfd);
        dlclose(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    long number_of_symbols = bfd_canonicalize_symtab(abfd, symbol_table);

    if (number_of_symbols <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at get number: " << libName << std::endl;
        free(symbol_table);
        bfd_close(abfd);
        dlclose(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_symbols; ++i)
    {
        const char* function_name = symbol_table[i]->name;
        void*(*method)(void*) = (void*(*)(void*))dlsym(handle, function_name);
        if (dlerror() == NULL)
            functions[function_name] = method;
    }

    free(symbol_table);
    bfd_close(abfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Кроме того, нужно обеспечить закрытие "хэндлера" библиотеки:

```
void stop()
{
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

Функция main может выглядеть, например, так:

```
int main()
{
    if (start("./libfunctions.so") != EXIT_SUCCESS)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    void * ret = callFunction("func0", 1, 2);

    std::cout << *(int*)ret << std::endl;

    callFunction("func1", std::string("Hello"), std::string("World"));

    stop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Не забудем добавить необходимые хэддеры:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <bfd.h>
```

Компилируем с линковкой к ранее указанным библиотекам:

```
g++ main.cpp -lbfd -ldl
```

Сразу в глаза бросаются проблемы с возвращаемым значением.

Во-первых, функция должна перед возвращением преобразовывать его в тип void*, а во-вторых, после получения этого значения его надо преобразовать обратно в желаемый тип.

Кроме того, при вызове каждой функции необходимо указывать параметры именно **нужного ей** типа. Вот почему в вызове функции func1 я указал преобразование к std::string.

Но и на этом проблемы не заканчиваются. После обработки библиотеки map будет заполнен некоторым набором ненужных нам символов. Можно конечно добавить ещё какое-нибудь условие (например, функции не должны начинаться с нижнего подчёркивания). Возможно, библиотека libbfd содержит что-то, позволяющее решить эту проблему, но я не особо углублялся.

Универсальностью данное решение, очевидно, не обладает. Однако, оно может являться опорной точкой. И я был бы рад услышать дополнения и улучшения от более опытных программистов.

Comment: А зачем тут libbfd? Почему нельзя просто сохранить handle, возвращенный dlopen и потом каждый раз вызывать с ним и именем функции dlsym? Т.е. зачем тащить  всю таблицу имен функций в map? Или все это из-за крестовых дополнений к именам и `bfd_canonicalize_symtab()` их убирает?

Comment: @avp не не, я всего лишь преследовал цель автоматического определения набора функций, чтобы пользователь не должен был вручную прописывать все функции, которые лежат у него в библиотеке. extern "C" как раз и убирает эти крестовые дополнения, если я не ошибаюсь. Жать, что этот спецификатор запрещает использовать многие удобные штуки, в частности тип auto для возвращаемого значения. Здесь это было бы к месту.

Comment: Ага, я просто не обратил внимания на `extern "C" ...`. Редко когда есть цель вызвать все, что есть в либе. Обычно вызывают только несколько нужных для задачи. А `extern "C"` на `auto` вроде бы не влияет. Компилятор по идее должен выводить тип из прототипа в исходнике (в .h)

Comment: Кстати, про передачу параметров в x86 [я как-то отвечал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/151697/232). Думаю, примитивный результат (целое/double/адрес) можно достать аналогичным способом.

Comment: Охх, как же все муторно. Не думал, что все так сложно. 
Но спасибо, за труд. Тут просто получается ф-ии поставляется gtk. А это все присоединить каким то образом, сложно думаю будет. 
Вся суть в одном, то что все это должно прям как-то в рантайме определяться, количество аргументов и все это, вот и в этом беда.

Comment: А что насчет ffi? Как оно работает?

Comment: @HackMemory я понял Вас. Скорее всего этот метод не подойдёт. Не знаю, что там лежит в gtk, но уверен, что там далеко не все функции void*(void*). Про ffi почти ничего не знаю, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

если Вам необходимо вызывать функцию именно по имени указанном в виде строки, то первое что приходит в голову так это объявить двумерный массив с именами и сопоставленными им адресами функций.
Для наглядности, можно определить структуру описывающую элемент массива:

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    void* func;
} funcnames_t;
```

далее объявите массив:

```
funcnames_t arr[3] = {
    { "func1", (void*) func1 },
    { "func2", (void*) func2 },
    { "func3", (void*) func3 }
};
```

следующим шагом у Вас перебор массива для поиска нужного элемента и вызов функции.

для передачи переменного количества параметров указанной функции, наверное стоит использовать опять же массив.
т.е. вид вызываемых функций должен быть примерно следующим:

```
void func(int argc, void** argv);
```

смысл думаю понятен.

если принять, что функция выглядит именно так как указал я, то первую структуру можно привести к виду:

```
typedef void (*func_t)(int, void**);

typedef struct {
    char* name;
    func_t func;
} funcnames_t;
```

а Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(funcnames_t); i++) {
    if (!strcmp(arr[i].name, funcname)) {
        arr[i].func(num_params, params);
    }
}
```

ЗЫ: код не претендует на работоспособность и призван лишь дать представление о логике.

Comment: Чтобы дать представление о логике, вы б лучше взяли `std::map` (а то и `unordered_map`). Тут же С++, а не С в метках :)

Answer (score -1):

Решение близко к тому, что Вам нужно. Возможно, что оно даже Вас устроит. Нашёл [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403872/7284712). Продублирую в этом ответе:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Fn, Fn fn, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type
wrapper(Args&&... args)
{
    return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

#define WRAPPER(FUNC, ...) wrapper<decltype(&FUNC), &FUNC>(__VA_ARGS__)

int myFunc0(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

std::string myFunc1()
{
    return "Some string";
}

int main()
{
    auto var1 = WRAPPER(myFunc0, 1, 2);
    auto var2 = WRAPPER(myFunc1);

    std::cout << var1 << std::endl << var2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*Компилятор должен поддерживать современные стандарты языка C++.*

Comment: Как это связано с желанием вызвать функцию по имени, заданному строкой?

Comment: @alexolut Здесь этого нет. Но давайте дождёмся ответа автора. Быть может ему нет необходимости получать имена функций в рантайме.

Comment: Таки, как раз надо именно получить название ф-ии в рантайме

Comment: @HackMemory что ж... Ещё одна попытка)