# Как получить указатель на первый аргумент функции?

Tags: c++, указатели, функции, memory, стек

У меня есть функция с определенным количеством параметров.
Но мне нужно избегать в теле функции обращение к любому параметру:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(int32 parm1, FString parm2, UObject* parm3)
{
   void* firstParmPtr = ?;  // как мне получить указатель? Где находится адрес первого параметра?
}
```

Значение указателя `firstParmPtr` должно быть равно `&parm1`.

Нашел интересный момент. Аргументы находятся в стеке, как и новые переменные. Таким образом я могу определить одну переменную в теле функции и вычесть размер всех аргументов функции (есть способ это сделать).

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(int32 parm1, FString parm2, UObject* parm3)
{
   uint64 _framePtr;
   UFunction* func = FindFunction("MyMethod");
   void* firstParmPtr = &_framePtr - func->ParamsSize;  // Вроде оно...
}
```

Однако этот вариант не работает. `_framePtr` слишком далеко в стеке от списка параметров. На много больше чем `sizeof` каждого параметра.
Тогда как мне действовать? Может нужно вычесть ещё какую-то константу?

Нужна любая информация об этом. А так же интересен адрес возвращаемого значения. А ещё желательно без использования ассемблерных вставок. Хотя можно и их, но это не главный объект интереса, так-как я не смогу такое компилировать.

Comment: Кое-какая информация есть в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/151697/232). Вообще, все тут зависит от архитектуры компа. Уточните архитектуру и поточнее сформулируйте конечную цель, может и разберемся.

Comment: Вы, я надеюсь, понимаете, что оптимизатор не то, что может просто заинлайнить вашу функцию, он может вообще выкинуть её вычисление, если сможет доказать, что её результат никому не интересен?

Comment: Ответ: никак не получить. Откуда вообще могла возникнуть такая идея? С чего вы взяли, что аргументы находятся в стеке?

Comment: На AMD64 и ARM часть параметров передаётся через регистры.

Comment: Между прочим, вы совсем забыли о параметре `this`. А теперь, если можно - самый главный вопрос - зачем? Это вопрос всерьез, потому что, может, вы просто спрашиваете, как правильно держать микроскоп, чтобы забивать гвозди, а правильно было бы спросить - как гвозди забивать? Может, ваша основная задача решается как-то совсем иначе?

Comment: Вопрос, возникающий чуть ли не в каждой фразе сообщения - "зачем?".

Comment: @Harry, у меня есть два контекста, где есть функции с одинаковой сигнатурой.
Работаю я во фреймворке Unreal Engine 4 (есть рефлексия). И так получается, что одна функция в одном контексте должна вызывать функцию с такой же сигнатурой в другом. Я не хочу вручную копировать названия параметров, (делать нечто вроде этого: `void func(int a) { otherObj->func(a); }`). Я могу найти функцию по её имени через `__FUNCTION__` и систему рефлексии (поиск метода), и я могу вызвать её используя данные в памяти через указатель как аргументы. Осталось придумать как получить указатель на эти данные.

Comment: @avp, так как это кроссплатформенный фреймворк, мне важно, чтобы это работало на любой архитектуре. Возможно используя какие-то директивы для разных архитектур...

Comment: Кроссплатформенно, да еще без ограничений (точнее указаний как надо делать) на оптимизацию, точно не сделать.

Comment: Что же касается вашего дополнительного описания в комментарии, то я так и не понял, почему передаваемые в выбираемую функцию (одну их двух) аргументы вам в точке вызова не известны? (имена переменных или их адреса). Впрочем, поскольку у вас С++, то наверное основная проблема с моделированием this?

Comment: Мда... Сигнатуры вам доступны? Вы можете менять код? Может, тогда объединять все параметры в одну структуру, и передавать ее? Но, как по мне, то искать функцию по имени, и пытаться передавать через указатель параметры - это уже что-то запредельно сложное... Кроме того, как я понимаю, вы хотите передать вызываемой функции ее параметры не в новом фрейме стека, а прямо в старом? Вы уверены, что эта овчинка стоит выделки?

Comment: @avp, не очень понимаю каким боком тут this. Он как параметр-указатель занимает 8 байт в текущем фрейме. Верно? Однако там гораздо больший отрыв локальной переменной до параметров, чем 8 байт. 
Да, кроссплатформенно, быть может директивами компилятору сделать несколько вариантов для разных архитектур. У меня даже скорее больше академический интерес, нежели практический.
Аргументы известны. Они нужны для генерации кода и рефлексии UE4, но для меня они формальность (нечто вроде эллипсиса: `...`, но без предшествующего параметра).

Comment: @Harry, сигнатуры доступны. Рефлексивная информация о функции есть. Код менять в реал-тайме не могу. Почему же сложное? Возможно не совсем типичное для С++, но оно существует во фреймворке как нормальное явление. Да, именно в старом. Я просто хочу передать указатель на эти данные (может быть скопировать предварительно их).
Выглядит это примерно так: `UFunction* func = FindFunction("FuncName"); ProcessEvent(func, paramsPtr);`

Comment: Если речь зашла о 8 байтах, то давайте конкретно. Про какой комп, ОС и компилятор идет речь?

Comment: @avp, на текущий момент у меня Win64, Intel i7 4820K, Visual Studio.
Но потенциально оно будет компилиться и на других ОС (скорее всего не х32), процах и компиляторах (например gcc, clang).

Comment: Ну, с M$ не хочу ковыряться.